# If I don't perform ghusl according to sunnah, would my ghusl be valid?

Tags: sunnah, ghusl

The information I got while searching for Ghusl on internet. There is Farā'id and Sunnah in Ghusl where Farā'id are important steps and Sunnah are optional.

By the information I got,
Farā'id are [*source*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghusl#Far.C4.81.27id_of_Ghusl)

- Rinsing the inner mouth.

  Sniffing water and blowing it out.

  To wash the entire body in a rigorous manner.

& Sunnah are [*source*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghusl#Sunnah_of_Ghusl)

- Washing both the hands up to the wrists.

  Wash the private parts and remove dirt or filth from the body.

  Perform Wudu.

  Water should be poured over the head three times so that it flows all over the body.

  Pour water on the right shoulder three times.

  Pour water on the left shoulder three times.

**My question, what if I don't perform Sunnah *"as these are optional"* then is my Ghusl right?**

Comment: If this is true my ghusl is always wrong and inavlid! But i think you refer to a speacial school of fiqh!

Comment: @Medi1Saif please help with this ghusl related query: https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/43616/18985

Answer (score 1):

I hope this link is helpful as it references Ibn Uthaymeen: http://islamqa.info/en/10790
Ghusl is categorized into sufficient and complete. The Fard makes it sufficient and the Sunnah completes it.
The Prophet (SAW) has enjoined us to hold steadfast to his sunnah as is seen in the hadiths below:

> It was narrated on the authority of Abu Najih al-Irbad bin Sariyah (ra) who said:
>
> "The Messenger of Allah (sas) delivered an admonition that made our hearts fearful and our eyes tearful. We said, "O Messenger of Allah, it is as if this were a farewell sermon, so advise us." He said, "I enjoin you to have Taqwa of Allah and that you listen and obey, even if a slave is made a ruler over you. He among you who lives long enough will see many differences. So for you is to observe my Sunnah and the Sunnah of the rightly-principled and rightly-guided successors, holding on to them with your molar teeth. Beware of newly-introduced matters, for every innovation (bid'ah) is an error."

(Abu Dawud & Al-Tirmidhi, who says it is an authentic hadith - hasan saheeh)

> Narrated 'Abdullah:
>
> "The best talk (speech) is Allah's Book 'Quran), and the best way is the way of Muhammad, and the worst matters are the heresies (those new things which are introduced into the religion); and whatever you have been promised will surely come to pass, and you cannot escape (it)".

Holding Fast to the Quran and Sunnah; Sahih Bukhari

Comment: is it for **sunnah mu'akkadah** or for **sunnah ghair mu'akkadah - optional** or for **both**?