# Would it be considered a valid Ghusl if I had a bit instant adhesive stuck near thumb nail while taking Ghusl and it is still there after the Ghusl?

Tags: fiqh, taharah, ghusl

I was fixing my broken specs with an instant adhesive (super glue) and a bit of it got stuck near my hand's thumb-nail and finger-nail.

I tried to remove it while taking Ghusl but it didn't get washed away completely and now after Ghusl I still have a bit of it near both nails.

I want to ask that is my Ghusl valid as I've listened that each and every small part of the body should be drenched in water for completion of Ghusl.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

No, for Ghusl to be complete, one must ensure that water passes over every part of his body. Since, the adhesive, super glue in this case, prevents water from flowing t the spot of skin, ghusl will be incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are limits to Islamic practices, from the heart vs excessive/obsessive behavior and worrying. As long as you cannot get it off, you tried yet it simply must come off naturally, in this case I would believe you are fine.